# Data size of result with join, how to optimize?

Tags: sql, join

Suppose I have a query of the form:

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl1
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.id = tbl2.user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl3 on tbl3.submit_id = tbl2.user_id
.....................................................
LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl3123 on tbl3123.mega_id = tbl223.super_hyper_id;
```

And I need to compute data size of the result (i.e. row count). Can I remove all of that LEFT OUTER JOIN and write just the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tbl1
```

Is result I reveive correct?

Comment: No.  The other tables may have duplicate ids that result in an explosion of rows.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Is there a way to optimize the query in general case, independent on the tables?

Comment: There are ways to get the record count and the results.  They depend on the RDBMS and/or the application you are using to run the query.  You specified neither.

Comment: You want to optimize the performance of the first query ? If yes, you should make sure indexes are properly set.

Comment: @Ndech Yes, I do, The thing is I have had too much indexes already.

Comment: If your rules are that you can join any (unknown) number of tables together, and there is no way to predict which of them can be on the 'many' side of the join...then the answer is no.  But surely there must be a more specific goal you have in mind -- i.e., something specific you're trying to count...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not, because one line in your table *tbl1* can match multiple records in any other tables.

This query :

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tbl1
```

only gives a lower bound, you can be sure that there will be at least that many records in the result.

Comment: Can the query be opmized in general case?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to generalize this without knowing the joins in advance becasue the count will vary depending on which tables are in the joins and what the where clauses are.

Suppose you have tablea and tableb

Tablea left joined to tableb is 118 rows, table a inner joined to tableb is 107 rows, tablea has 89 rows and tableb has 107 rows and 11 rows of tableA have no tableb record. This is because tablea is in a one to many relationship to table b and there is not alawys a record created in tableb when tablea records are created.

Or it is possible that Tablea left joined to tableb is 1,00,786 rows, table a inner joined to tableb is 987,123 rows when  tablea has 89 rows (becasue inthis case the one-many is very many!). Or you could have a one to one realtionships where tablea has 89 records, tableb has 89 records and both joins have 89 records. Or table b coudl have orphaned reciords that don't exist in table A becasue you designed the datbase badly without referential integrity. Or table b could be the pranet table and tablea the child table.

There is simply no way to know the count until you add in the joins (and any where clauses).